# Count values in dataframe column that include specific parameters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with ~150k columns:

[Dataframe: Information about Salaries and Employees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvuxa.png)
I need to count specific values in the `Job Title` column of the dataframe, but it has to be a count of the values that include `'chief'` somewhere within the job title.

I tried bringing up all the unique job titles up with `value_counts`, but there are too many still for me to count.

```
print("%s employees have 'chief' in their job title." % salaries['JobTitle'].value_counts())
```

How can I create the specific condition I need to count the values correctly?

Comment: @ananvodo Thank you! That link was exactly what I needed.  I couldn't find a duplicate anywhere.

Comment: @RockoBishop ok , so I close this as dup, is that ok ?

Comment: That's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
salaries['JobTitle'].str.contains('chief').sum()
```